# Have been deported from the US and trying to get visa for Canada. The consequences?

Tags: usa, visa, canada, bangladeshi-citizens

I was **deported** from the US in 2015 for 'F-1' student visa violation. I worked outside without a work permit.

Point: They didn’t catch me from any working place. For some reason I was called into immigration control and I made a truthful statement at the immigration interview. Afterwords, my visa got canceled. As I heard from one of the immigration officers, my travel ban would be for **5 years**. After 5 years, I can apply for another visa. He mentioned to me, "Don't try to enter the country within the ban period, it would be a crime then."

Anyway, I haven’t tried to apply yet. The five year ban has lapsed (2015-2020).

After US deportation, I arrived in **South Korea** to complete my undergraduate studies. I'm living here without any single violation in the last 4 years and I have graduated this year with a degree in 'Railway Engineering'. Now, I'm thinking of applying for a job or for my **Masters/integrated PhD** program in the the US or probably Canada.

What could be the **consequences** if I apply for the US?

As far as I know, they're sharing databases, so would this be a consideration if I apply for Canada?

I called to the US embassy in Seoul. They gave me the **CBP** number to ask them:

1. Is my ban period done?
2. If I want to apply for another visa, is there any additional paper I should get from them?

Well, I have tried to reach them but it's always machines picking up the call and I never get any human to answer.

I have a contacted some universities. They might accept me as a lab researcher. But, I'm worried that if after all this, I would not even be able to apply!

Comment: Your ban may be finished but that doesn't mean you'll get a visa. You've broken the rules once so the suspicion will be that you'll do it again. You'll have to work hard to convince an immigration officer that you won't. We can't predict the outcome and neither can the embassy staff. The only way to get a result is to apply.

Comment: Having a bad **travel record** will always have consequences, especially so in jurisdictions where *forgiveness* is not strongest aspect of their juristic process.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Comment: I'm a Bangladeshi.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the consequences if I apply for the US?

For just applying, there will be no technical consequences as long as your applications is genuine and contains only truthful factual information. But applying so shortly after your previous ban has lapsed will certainly raise some eyebrows. It's just human nature.

> Is my ban period done?

You seem to have answered this part earlier yourself. Since you didn't provide the exact date of the ban period (DD-MM-YYYY), we can only work off what you've stated.

> If I want to apply for another visa, is there any additional paper I should get from them?

No, but you may be asked to provide extra details in the application itself to explain the ban.

> The consequences?

As has been stated in the comments, this will haunt just about every application you make in every country in the world for years to come, possibly for decades. As you build up a positive travel/immigration history, like you've done with South Korea, the negative effects will ease up a bit for some jurisdictions. And time eventually heals all wounds to some degree. But you should never have your hopes too high when applying for a visa for the United States again. It is speculation to say how any specific application will every go, so afraid we can't help with that.